# Dynamically applying setter decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am looking for a way to write a decorator that wraps the property and setter decorators. Ideally, this decorator will perform some simple work, then return a version of the method decorated with `@property` or `@propertyname.setter`. I was imagining something like this for `@property`, but cannot think of a way to express it:

```
def my_property_decorator(func):
    def decorator(*args):
        # do some work here

        # apply regular property decorator
        @property(func) # this is not correct syntax
        return func(*args)

    return decorator
```

For the setter, I am even more at a loss because I would have to get the name of the property being decorated so I can compose the full name of the decorator, but I'm not sure how I would be able to apply the decorator when I have its name as a string.

I think I could probably just stack decorators like this:

```
@property
@my_property_decorator
def prop(self):
    # implementation


@prop.setter
@my_setter_decorator
def prop(self, newVal):
    # implementation
```

But wanted to see if there was a cleaner solution that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that decorators are just standard Python objects, i.e. mostly classes and functions.  also remember that:

```
@decorator
def foo():
  pass
```

is just short for

```
def foo():
  pass
foo = decorator(foo)
```

you could therefore write your code like:

```
def my_property_decorator(func):
    @property
    def decorator(*args):
        # do some work here
        return func(*args)
    return decorator
```

or like:

```
def my_property_decorator(func):
    func = property(func)
    def decorator(*args):
        # do some work here
        return func(*args)
    return decorator
```

or even:

```
def my_property_decorator(func):
    def decorator(*args):
        # do some work here
        return func(*args)
    return property(decorator)
```

depending on what was appropriate and/or clearer

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the first part! I would really appreciate if you could also suggest a solution for the setter issue (where the name of the decorator depends on the name of the property, and I don't know how to invoke it based on the string representation of its name)

Comment: I have figured out a way to do this. I can simply pass the property into my setter decorator like this `@my_setter_decorator(prop)`, then use that reference to decorate the inner returned function with `@prop.setter`. Thank you for getting me on the right track!